# How do I remove a download that wasn't completed?

Tags: apt, gdebi

I was trying to install android studio via apt-get on my ubuntu gnome 15.10 amd64 machine and then I noticed that it was trying to download android-studio-ide-141.2422023-linux.zip which was around 363 mb and on my slow internet connection it was taking too long.I quit the terminal and started installing some other conky-manager.deb package via gdebi and then gdebi started downloading the same(android-studio-ide-141.2422023-linux.zip) file anyways. Everytime I quit gdebi and try to install the conky-manager.deb package again, gdebi starts the download again. Now I know that the two packages are not related in anyway therefor the android-studio-ide-141.2422023-linux.zip. cannot be a dependancy for conky-manager. My question is how do I stop this download and proceed with the download  and installation of the actual dependancies for conky-manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

If it errors out with a "lock error" (*) or if you want to do it yourself ...

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/
ls
```

The directory should be empty but your system will have the yet to finish .DEB files. Use a `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*` (safey 1st ;) )  to delete all or change the `*` for an actual file name. Do not delete the directory "partial/".

(*) if you are sure nobody is using the installer and the lock error is not correct you can remove the lock with

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock    
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```